# What is common data migration strategy for Core Data in iOS development?

Tags: ios, core-data, data-migration

If data model changes,and need be backward compatible to use old data source,we must consider data migration for database application.

What is the common strategy for core data in iOS dev ? Is there any mature open source project to handle this problem ?

Comment: This will help me understand more about iOS http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmMappingOverview.html