# Core Data migrations with Magical Record

Tags: ios, ios5, core-data-migration, magicalrecord

I use Core Data and MagicalRecord for my application's database.

How can I migrate my database without uninstalling the application when I add a new model to the database?

Comment: Do you mean how can you migrate your store after you update your model?

Comment: Yes. How I can do this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a  look at this question, and the tutorial posted.

[What is common data migration strategy for Core Data in iOS development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601339/what-is-common-data-migration-strategy-for-core-data-in-ios-development)

Here's another:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/27657/how-to-perform-a-lightweight-core-data-migration

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [How to migrate core data by deleting old one on App Update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18977752/1588258) 
Since you have already done the pre configuration for Magical Record, everything else will be taken care of, Cheers!